# Wordpress: Combine external database table and WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I've got a custom post type 'locations' and each location has a postal code.

And I have another table with all postal codes of the country and their coordinates (longitude, latitude).

Now I want to display all existing locations within a given radius around a given postal code. I do know how to calculate the distance.

Do I have to select all possible postal codes first and then execute WP_Query with the meta_key = 'postalcode' and the meta_value IN [My list of possible postal codes], or is there any way to directly JOIN the tables using WP_Query?

I do need WP_Query, because I want to use Wordpress features like Pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the global $wpdb to get the data from 2 or more tables. Stuff like pagination and many more can be done with $wpdb by passing custom $paged parameter and pagination function.

Reference : [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Example of pagination with $wpdb : [Pagination with $wpdb](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53194/wordpress-paginate-wpdb-get-results)

use `$wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A)` to get multiple rows
use `$wpdb->get_row($query,ARRAY_A)` to get single row